# Prestashop API: Prestapyt: Display orders details since date

Tags: python, api, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

How to get orders details since specific date by Prestashop API? I'm using https://github.com/prestapyt/prestapyt .

Is `search()` return only ids?

Should I use `search()` and iterate `get('orders', id)` ? Is it properly way? Or maybe can I reduce this way and get object from something like this: `get('orders', fewIDs)`, and then iterate result ?